# How to remove the white space around showMenu

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

There is a white space around my pop up view that is implemented in onLongPress(). Can't seem to get rid of it. The code is as follows:

```
Expanded(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              debugPrint('Container clicked');
            },
            onLongPress: () {
              showMenu(
                context: context,
                position: RelativeRect.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0.0, 0.0),
                items: <PopupMenuEntry>[
                  PopupMenuItem(
                    child: getPopUpView(context),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            },
            child: Column( ...
```

And in the getPopUpView method we have :

```
    Container getPopUpView(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
    width: 278,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
      color: BPColor.grey1,
    ),
    child: Column(
      children: [
        popUpViewRows(
            context, AppLocalizations.of(context).markText, Assets.iconStar),
        Divider(
          color: BPColor.black,
        ),
        popUpViewRows(context, AppLocalizations.of(context).archiveText,
            Assets.iconArchive),
        Divider(
          color: BPColor.black,
        ),
        popUpViewRows(
            context, AppLocalizations.of(context).selectText, Assets.iconStar),
        Divider(
          color: BPColor.black,
        ),
        popUpViewRows(context, AppLocalizations.of(context).function2Text,
            Assets.iconStar),
        Divider(
          color: BPColor.black,
        ),
        popUpViewRows(context, AppLocalizations.of(context).deleteText,
            Assets.iconDelete),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

In the popUpViewRows method we have :

```
    GestureDetector popUpViewRows(BuildContext context, String text, String icon) {
  return GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {
      debugPrint('$text clicked');
    },
    child: Row(
      children: [
        Center(
          child: Text(
            text,
            style: BPFonts.popUpViewtextStyle,
          ),
        ),
        Spacer(),
        SvgPicture.asset(
          icon,
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

The Output looks like this:

[image]

As you see, There is a white space around the popup view. I am not sure why this border looking thing is present. And showMenu does not seem to have a border attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. I was able to figure it out. Simpler than I thought.
All I had to do was add a color attribute to the showMenu, can't believe it took me so long to think of that.
So I did this :

```
showMenu(
                color: BPColor.grey1,
                context: context,
                position: RelativeRect.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0.0, 0.0),
                items: <PopupMenuEntry>[
                  PopupMenuItem(
                    child: getPopUpView(context),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            },
```

Answer (score 0):

Use constraints feature inside the `PopupMenuButton` and give it `BoxConstraints` sizes of your choice. Example below:

```
PopupMenuButton<int>(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
  constraints: BoxConstraints(
    maxHeight: 150.0,
    maxWidth: 150,
  ),
)
```